# TextChanged Event how to determine what's changed

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-metro

I working on a project. I have text boxes and with TextChanged event I changed the text to upperCase

txt.ToUpper();

and after that the selectionStart starts at the beginning. I changed that to textbox.text.length .

how can I determine the changes? I want to move selectionStart to where the user made the change in the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the the previous text in a variable, say, `previousVariable`, initialized with `null`.

```
string prevVal = null;
private void txtSel_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(prevVal == null)
    {
        prevVal = txtSel.Text;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < txtSel.Text.length; i++)
        {
            if(txtSel.Text.Substring(i, 1) != prevVal.Substring(i, 1))
            {
                txtSel.SelectionStart = i+1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Try using the above code on selection change.

Comment: This is really fragile. (For example, when pasting.) It will also break when text is just added at the end.

Comment: I also thought of this but I have 3-20 textboxes per page.

Comment: Sorry . but I did not paste the code wrote it down here ... :) did not see where the cursor to the code section went wrong. thanks for the correction :)

Comment: have a common selection change for each element and keep a track of the last changed text box name or index ...

Comment: typecast the sender object as 

((TextBox)sender).Text use this rather than txtSel.text that I wrote

Comment: ok but I must update prevVal after I set the selectionStart and must use string variables for every textboxes I have

Comment: Yes prevVal must be updated constantly and better if you maintain a key value pair . Do some thing update the prevVal on focus first to store the current data then compare it in the textchanged and set the cursor. Theres no direct method to go through it so u will have to code it through. Forgive me if i spell or write wront m using a note currently

Comment: @Anobik I got 1 problem left now. When I Type at the end, the if case crashes for prevVal gets "Index and length must refer to a location within the string." error

Comment: I can use a counter. at got focus the counter sets to zero and increases everytime in the textChanged event and checks and do stuff when counter is even.

Comment: Yes, But tell me one thing weather you would like to do it for a particular textbox that are even in position with respect to the parent child relation. ?

Comment: sorry but I dont get it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36922/discussion-between-anobik-and-eomer)